# how can I create a new mail folder?

Tags: email, folders

How do I create a new folder in my mail.

I've have gone through every menu option I can see and don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail uses the word "mailbox" instead of folder.

In the left sidebar, right-click (or Control-click if on a laptop) and select "New Mailbox" from the contextual menu. You will be prompted with a message similar to: "Enter name for new mailbox to be created inside “[parent folder name]” in account “[account name]”.

Comment: Great Thanks!  The thing now is that folders are created in the "Exchange" or "On my mac" areas and I don't have the option to add them there... unless I'm using the web client and then I can (and when I sync they show up locally in my local Mailboxes area.